# Symbol reference resolution for dynamically loaded libraries on linux

Tags: linux, gcc, ld, dynamic-loading

I was trying to understand how symbols are resolved in case of dynamically loaded libraries. I observed that the symbols of the libraries are resolved using the libs linked as the dynamic dependencies to the library. The same can be listed using - `ldd <share_file_name.so>`

Is this correct?

Earlier I assumed that the loader will look at the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and will look at all the libraries for resolving the symbols in the library.
But now I think about it then I can see why this approach might not be used. The reason is that it will be very in-optimised way of resolving the symbols if the loader has to look at all the libraries at the directories listed in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. What if the directory has a million files then it will be very slow as any file can have the symbol.

Comment: [`man ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) contains the information you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Loader *basically* works by scanning all loaded libraries in the order in which they have been loaded (first direct dependencies of main executable, then their dependencies, etc.). Usually symbols which your library needs will be resolved from it's own dependencies (which you can find by running `readelf -l` or `ldd` on your library). But if some other preceding library already provided them, they'll be resolved from there (this is called symbol interposition and is used for various tricks like `LD_PRELOAD` or [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so)).

There are many more details which may influence loaders decision (`-Bsymbolic`, symbol versioning, etc.) which are explained e.g. in canonical [How to write shared libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) document.

Comment: `Usually symbols which your library needs will be resolved from it's own dependencies (which you can find by running readelf -l or ldd on your library)` - Is my understanding that -if a symbol is not there in the dependencies then the executable will not start as linker doesn't know which dependency has the symbol, correct?

Comment: Also LD_LIBRARY_PATH has nothing to do with the symbol resolution. It's just set of directories where linker searches for the dependencies which we can list using `ldd <name_of_executable>`.

Comment: "if a symbol is not there in the dependencies then the executable will not start as linker doesn't know which dependency has the symbol" - are you talking about static or dynamic linker (aka loader)? If symbol is not present at link time, static linker will abort unless you run it with "-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined". If symbol is not present at runtime, dynamic linker will not abort but keep running until you try to call the function (at which point it will terminate execution), unless you run with `LD_BIND_NOW` (then it will fail at start).

Comment: In generate there are a lot of details which alter the way that symbol resolution works so I encourage you to read Drepper's paper which I've cited in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sure I will go through the paper.